# Campo com Cedilha em Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Possuo um campo em minha tabela do banco de dados *MySql* com o nome 'descrição', com os acentos especiais.

O meu problema é:
Quando faço um `INSERT INTO` utilizando diretamente o *phpMyAdmin*, ele insere normalmente a informação na tabela, porém ao usar o *mysql* na aplicação ele retorna o seguinte erro.

[image: erro sql]

Este é o meu código sql:

```
INSERT INTO caixa_geral_dc (
descrição,
empresa,
valor_c_d,
conta,
categoria,
d_c,
usuario)
VALUES 
('GUARDA PROVISÓRIA DE VALORES',
'$nome_cliente[$i]',
'$v_recebido&[$i]',
'7',
'197',
'c',
'$_SERVER[nomeUsuario]')
```

Aguardo respostas.

Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você tem algum campo com caracteres especiais ou espaços em branco nele, esse campo deve ser declarado dentro de ``

Segue como deveria ficar sua query:

```
INSERT INTO caixa_geral_dc ( `descrição`, empresa, valor_c_d, conta, categoria, d_c, usuario) VALUES ('GUARDA PROVISÓRIA DE VALORES', '$nome_cliente[$i]', '$v_recebido&[$i]', '7', '197', 'c', '$_SERVER[nomeUsuario]')
```

Comment: Unknown column 'descrição' in 'field list'

Comment: Este foi o resultado. :\

Comment: seu campo está realmente escrito como descrição no banco?

Comment: @netoweb utilize ` ao invés de '

Comment: @netoweb lembrando que é uma crase e n uma aspas simples

Comment: Sim sim. Utilizei a crase e mesmo assim ele continua dando erro. Infelizmente o campo no banco está descrição... Estamos trocando de Access para Web.

Answer (score 3):

Coloque o nome do seu campo entre ` para sinalizar que o mesmo é um campo(isto também serve para nomes restritos e/ou com espaços)

```
INSERT INTO caixa_geral_dc ( `descrição`, empresa, valor_c_d, conta, categoria, d_c, usuario) VALUES ('GUARDA PROVISÓRIA DE VALORES', '$nome_cliente[$i]', '$v_recebido&[$i]', '7', '197', 'c', '$_SERVER[nomeUsuario]')
```

Comment: Fiz o que você me recomendou.
Obrigado pela ajuda, porém ele agora retorna:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[descrição], ' at line 2

Comment: @netoweb Vou dar uma olhada e já te dou um retorno

Comment: Ok. Obrigado pela ajuda, amigo

Comment: Atualizada, porem também enviaram uma nova resposta

Comment: Pela primeira vez me deparei com essa situação, rsrsrs

Comment: o nome não pode ser alterado ?

Comment: Vou conversar com meu supervisor a respeito. Qualquer coisa retorno aqui

Comment: Infelizmente não será alterado por agora.

Answer (score 1):

Galera. Obrigado a todos pela ajuda, mas resolvi meu problema.
Bastava adicionar a linha

mysql_set_charset('utf8');

no arquivo conexao.php para funcionar.

Lembrando que também a adição da crase antes de descrição, resolveu o problema.

Ficou assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado messssmo!
Até mais! :D

Comment: Perfeito, esta eu não sabia haha

Comment: kkkk vivendo & aprendendo rsrs